# SQL Statement - Declaring Multiple Values with Numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I want to generate a new column from a table that contains the values 0 or 1. These values are to indicate whether another column contains a value that occurs more than once in the database.

For example:

Table :

```
Attribute 1 
A 
B 
C 
A 
B 
F 
A 
B 

Attribute New
1
1
0
1
1
0
1
1
```

and so on...  I have already tried it with CASE and HAVING, but somehow I can't find the desired solution. Anybody got any ideas?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Group BY` and `COUNT` on subquery and Self `join` by `count` which is bigger then one,then you can use `CASE` Expression on `select` clause.

You can try like this.

```
SELECT T1.val,CASE WHEN  T2.val IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END  as [New]
FROM 
T AS T1
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT val,COUNT(1)  'totle'
  FROM T
  GROUP BY val
) AS T2 ON T2.totle > 1  and t1.val = t2.val
```

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ca346/1

Comment: You can change the `LEFT JOIN` with inner join too. In that case use the case statement to check `CASE WHEN  T2.totle > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: This works excellent :) But the new column name was not transferred?

Comment: @Liam0711 I add the column name field:)

Comment: @Liam0711 Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the DECODE like should work:

```
Select a1,
 CASE PAttribute_1 
 WHEN (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM T WHERE a1 = p.a1 ) > 1 THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: This is hard coding , OP wants if there could be more entries

Comment: Thank you, but then I have to enter everyone worth? I would like to automatically rate the values which occur more than once with 1?

Comment: I edited answer, idea is to use an inner select to count whether occurrencies are more than 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use many attributes to get the required output

sample data:

```
declare @table table (attribute1 varchar(3))

insert @table (attribute1)

select 'A' union all 
 select 'B' union all 
select 'C' union all 
select 'A' union all 
select 'B' union all 
select 'F' union all 
select 'A' union all 
select 'B'
```

;
query:

```
with cte as
(
select attribute1, max(rn) rn
from (
select attribute1, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by attribute1 order by attribute1) rn
from @table ) x
group by attribute1
) select c.attribute1, case when c.rn>1 then 1 else 0 end Attribute_new
from @table t inner join cte c on  t.attribute1 = c.attribute1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bothered about the order, you can use something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE T(val varchar(10));
INSERT INTO T VALUES 
('A'),
('B'),
('C'),
('A'),
('B'),
('F'),
('A'),
('B');


select  *, case when (count(val) over(partition by val)-1) = 0 then 0 else 1 end OneOrZero
from    T
```